# Comparing two fields from two files and printing the common items from the files with the count from each file

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk, sed, python

I have two files in a below-mentioned way

File1

```
Emp1 Dec10 12Am 
Emp2 Dec10 2Am 
Emp3 Dec10 4Am 
Emp2 Dec10 6Am 
Emp1 Dec10 8Am
```

File2

```
Emp1 Dec11 12Pm 
Emp2 Dec11 2Am 
Emp1 Dec11 3Am 
Emp3 Dec11 4Am 
Emp1 Dec11 5Am
```

So I am trying to get the output as

```
Emp1 presence on Dec10 was 2 times and on Dec11 was 3 times. 
Emp2 presence on Dec10 was 2 times and on Dec11 was 1 time. 
Emp3 presence on Dec10 was 1 time and on Dec11 was 1 time.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
EMP=(`awk '!seen[$1]++ {print $1}' File1 File2`)

for emp in "${EMP[@]}"
do
    DAYS=`awk -v b=$emp '$1==b {print $2}' File1 File2 | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2" was "$1" times"}' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ and on /g'`
    echo "$emp presence on $DAYS "
done
```

Comment: Thanks, It works like a gem. Can you please brief a bit on the regex that you have used in that with sed and awk ?